# Event scroll up and fixed header jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var lastScroll = 0;
    $(window).scroll(function(event){
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        if ((lastScroll - st) == 5) {
           $("header").css("position", "fixed");
        }
        else {
          $("header").css("position", "absolute");
        }
        lastScroll = st;
    });
  });
```

But I want, when I scroll up on 5px, header again shows.
How I can follow event scroll up 5px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're updating your lastScroll too often, to make sure it has scrolled past a certain delta (in your case 5px) you should include that clause before checking if the user has scroll up or down.

This [tutorial](https://medium.com/@mariusc23/hide-header-on-scroll-down-show-on-scroll-up-67bbaae9a78c#.4czc2q3ee) may help you, but I also created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lucaslazaro/rpgj0dgm/) with an updated version of your code.

But it would go like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var lastScroll = 0;
    $(window).scroll(function(event){
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        // Make sure they scroll more than delta
        if(Math.abs(lastScroll - st) <= 5)
            return;

        if (st < lastScroll) {
           $("header").css("position", "fixed");
        } else {
          $("header").css("position", "absolute");
        }
        lastScroll = st;
    });
  });
```